# Calculate the date difference everyday automatically

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

Below is my code, which takes the **`$_POST['antivirus_expiration_date'];`** , Current date and calculates the remaining days for the Antivirus license to expire.

```
$a_exp_date = $_POST['antivirus_expiration_date'];
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$date1=date_create($a_exp_date);
$date2=date_create($today);
$diff=date_diff($date2,$date1);
$countdown = $diff->format("%R%a days"); //Calculate this everyday
```

Now, this only works when I **`INSERT`** new antivirus in the database or **`UPDATE`** the existing entivirus record. If I do nothing, then the value calculated last time is displayed untill I **`UPDATE`** it again. How do I make it calculate the remaining days automatically everyday?

Comment: Resource Issues & performance degredation aside. you can simply update it once a day using a cron job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.  You store the date it was created in the database.  Then, when you need to use it, compute the value (dateDiff) upon retrieval.  It is not the job of the database to compute values and update itself daily and your current approach has this set as an expectation.